# Reverse track forced records relationships based on user-defined tagging

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table where the tagging [Tag_To] is updated by an algorithm based on Year and Period of coverage.  My current task (in question) is to update the Status given the Year.

```
ID   Year    Method    Period_From   Period_To    SeqNo   Tag_To       Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10   2019      A       2019-01-01    2019-12-31     1                  
11   2019      B       2019-01-01    2019-06-30     2       1          
12   2019      B       2019-07-01    2019-12-31     3       1          
13   2019      C       2019-01-01    2019-06-30     4       2          

14   2020      A       2020-01-01    2020-12-31     1                  
15   2020      B       2020-01-01    2020-06-30     2       1          
16   2020      B       2020-07-01    2020-12-31     3       1          
17   2020      C       2020-01-01    2020-12-31     4       2,3          

18   2021      A       2021-01-01    2021-12-31     1                  
19   2021      B       2021-01-01    2021-12-31     2       1          
20   2021      C       2021-07-01    2021-12-31     3       2
```

The **SeqNo** is applied per Year and the **Tag_To** is done based on period of coverage.

- 11 and 12 are tagged to 10 since B follows A and their period falls within 10 period coverage.
- 13 is tagged to 11 since C follows B and the period...
- 15 and 16 to 14
- Also note that 17 is tagged to **15 and 16** (2,3) because 17's coverage spans across the 2 periods of 15 and 16 combined
- and so on...

The objective is to update the **Status** by Year such that each path is considered **Closed** if the path already has Methods A, B and C (there are actually more methods, but to simplify).  Status should be **Open** for paths that haven't completed the methods.

From the example above, there are 5 paths:

1. 10(A)-->11(B)-->13(C) = Closed
2. 10(A)-->12(B)-->??? = Open
3. 14(A)-->15(B)-->17(C) = Closed
4. 14(A)-->16(B)-->17(C) = Closed
5. 18(A)-->19(B)-->20(C) = Closed

Therefore the status update should be:

```
ID   Year    Method    Period_From   Period_To    SeqNo   Tag_To       Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10   2019      A       2019-01-01    2019-12-31     1                  Open
11   2019      B       2019-01-01    2019-06-30     2       1          Closed
12   2019      B       2019-07-01    2019-12-31     3       1          Open
13   2019      C       2019-01-01    2019-06-30     4       2          Closed

14   2020      A       2020-01-01    2020-12-31     1                  Closed
15   2020      B       2020-01-01    2020-06-30     2       1          Closed
16   2020      B       2020-07-01    2020-12-31     3       1          Closed
17   2020      C       2020-01-01    2020-12-31     4       2,3        Closed


18   2021      A       2021-01-01    2021-12-31     1                  Closed 
19   2021      B       2021-01-01    2021-12-31     2       1          Closed
20   2021      C       2021-07-01    2021-12-31     3       2          Closed
```

I hope I have explained everything clearly.  Would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: I just don't understand why 10 is open and 11 is closed.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff.  It's because of Path #2 as defined in "There are 5 paths".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update viewers that I have managed to solve this on my own although the solution is super non-dynamic and quite inefficient, it pretty much did the job for me.  Here's what I did.

```
UPDATE Table SET 
    Status =
    CASE WHEN Method = 'B' 
            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Table P INNER JOIN 
                (
                SELECT VALUE AS Tag_To
                FROM Table AV
                CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(AV.Tag_To, ',') 
                WHERE AV.Method = 'C'
                ) C ON P.Sequence_No = C.Tag_To
            WHERE P.ID = AValue.ID
        ) 
            THEN 'Open'
        WHEN Method = 'A'
            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Table P INNER JOIN 
                (
                SELECT VALUE AS Tag_To
                FROM Table AV
                CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(AV.Tag_To, ',') 
                WHERE AV.Method = 'B'
                ) C ON P.Sequence_No = C.Tag_To
            WHERE P.ID = AValue.ID
        ) 
            THEN 'Open'
        ELSE 'Closed'
    END
FROM Table AValue
WHERE Year = @Year

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.Method ORDER BY A.Sequence_No ASC) SN,
        A.ID,
        A.Method,
        A.Sequence_No,
        A.Tag_To,
        A.Period_From,
        A.Period_To,
        A.Status
    FROM Table A
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
        SELECT VALUE AS Tag_To
        FROM Table AV
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(AV.Tag_To, ',') 
        WHERE Year = @Year
        ) B ON A.Sequence_No = B.Tag_To
    WHERE Year = @Year
),
CTE2 AS 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT SN FROM CTE
 WHERE Status = 'Open'
)
UPDATE Table SET
    Status = 'Open'
FROM Table 
INNER JOIN CTE ON Table.ID = CTE.ID
INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE.SN = CTE2.SN
```

Yeah, it's ugly but, hey, it did the job!  :)